# Convert SQL Server query to h2 query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, h2

I've been trying to write the following SQL Server query in h2 db for my integration test cases.

```
UPDATE
  Test.Table1 WITH (UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE)
SET
  field1 = :val1,
  field6 = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  field4 = :val4,
  field5 = :val5
WHERE
  field2 = :val2
  AND field3 = :val3;

IF @ @ROWCOUNT = 0 BEGIN
INSERT INTO
  Test.Table1(
    ID,
    field1,
    field2,
    field3,
    field4,
    field5,
    field6,
    field7,
    field8,
    field9
  )
VALUES
  (
    newid(),
    :val1,
    :val2,
    :val3,
    :val4,
    :val5,
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    :val4,
    :val5,
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
  );
END
```

I see that rowcount is not valid in h2. Hence tried writing using case commands which didn't seem to work either. Could anyone help here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same standard `MERGE` statement in **both** SQL Server and H2:

```
MERGE INTO TEST.TABLE1
USING (SELECT :val1 V1, :val2 V2, :val3 V3, :val4 V4, :val5 V5) S
ON (FIELD2 = V2 AND FIELD3 = V3)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET FIELD1 = V1, FIELD6 = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, FIELD4 = V4, FIELD5 = V5
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (ID, FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3, FIELD4, FIELD5, FIELD6, FIELD7, FIELD8, FIELD9)
VALUES (NEWID(), V1, V2, V3, V4, V5, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, V4, V5, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

I assume you're using a some wrapper to replace `:val*` with real values.

Comment: Hi, 

Thanks for the reply. But in my case, I cannot use a merge query since we have changed the existing merge query to the present one as merge query was taking longer to execute.

So I’ll have to write something similar to this in test cases as well. 

Just wondering is there a way to do so or is the merge query only option here for the test cases?

Comment: If `MERGE` is slower, it looks like a minor bug in SQL Server. Your custom query contains vendor-specific features and cannot be executed by H2 and others. I think you can't find anything similar, standard `MERGE` is the only portable pure SQL command for such purposes and if you don't like its behavior in the SQL Server, you need to conditionally execute different SQL in it and in H2. It's a very bad idea to use different DBMS for tests, and when you do it, you should be ready for such problems.

Comment: Yeah, so I’ve observed some requests takng more time and when I analysed for the reason I saw that the query was taking longer time, so I had to change it this way. Yeah if merge is the only option for h2, I can change it to merge for test cases itself. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know of any other in memory databases which would be compatible with this one?

Comment: No. H2 and HSQLDB have compatibility modes for the SQL Server, but they both provide only very limited compatibility and don't support such syntax.